# Except Chrome all the desktop apps are not working though there is an active Internet connection on my Mac

Tags: network, safari, wifi, google-chrome, dns

I tried:

- flushing DNS,
- adding new locations in Network Preferences,
- changing IP address
- adding Google DNS

but also only Google Chrome works fine. Other apps which run on Internet like Workplace, Viber and Safari are not working.

Please help me fix this problem as soon as possible.